# Cannot find the module 'babel-plugin-r'

Tags: babeljs

I am having the following error while running the react native code,please help me

error: index.js: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-r'
Require stack:

- /home/Documents/Assignment3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /home/Documents/Assignment3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /home/Documents/Assignment3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /home/Documents/Assignment3/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js
- /home/Documents/Assignment3/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.js
- /home/Documents/Assignment3/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js

Comment: show you bablerc file

Comment: Same question answered here. Have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972567/error-index-js-cannot-find-module-babel-plugin-r-react-native

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when i used **react navigation** which requires **react-native-reanimated**.
To resume, after following instructions mentionned in the [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/#babel-plugin),
i omitted the three points ... , as following:

```js
    module.exports = function (api) {
      api.cache(true);
      return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
        //...   <=== this three dots caused the problem
        plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
      };
    };
```

which resolved the problem for me.
Original answer link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972567/error-index-js-cannot-find-module-babel-plugin-r-react-native)